# VBA iterate drop down list

Tags: excel, vba, loops, drop-down-menu

I have a spread sheet with J1 being a drop down list. Content in row 8-14 would change based on what you choose in J1. I need to iterate through all values in the drop down list and copy all the corresponding rows to a new workbook. the copy paste part is working, but I am having problem iterating through the drop down list. particularly, I need some help to define Formula1. I am using excel 2010. Here is my code. Thanks in advance

```
Sub iterate_dropdown()
    Dim inputRange As Range
    Dim c As Range
    Dim Current As Range

    Set inputRange = Evaluate(Workbooks("sample.xlsm").Worksheets("Credit Research Journal").Range("J1").Validation.Formula1)
    For Each c In inputRange
        Workbooks("sample.xlsm").Worksheets("Credit Research Journal").Range("J1").Value = c.Value
        Workbooks("sample.xlsm").Sheets("Credit Research Journal").Activate
        Workbooks("sample.xlsm").RefreshAll
        FinalRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        Cells(8, 1).Resize(FinalRow - 7, 10).Copy
        Workbooks("Book2.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet3").Activate
        NextRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        Set Current = Cells(NextRow, 1)
        Current.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Next c

End Sub
```

Comment: Indent your code correctly. Edit your post and select all code segments and do `ctrl-k`. or `cmd-k` for mac.

Comment: does it look better?

Answer (score 0):

I did some experimenting with the code you posted, and it seems you were pretty close.  I discovered that the step where you were getting `inputRange` was including an equals sign (=), which then caused the Evaluate function to fail.

Here is the code I used:

```
 Sub iterate_dropdown()

    Dim inputRange As Range
    Dim c As Range
    Dim Current As Range
    Dim strRange As String
    Dim strRange2 As String
    strRange = Worksheets("Credit Research Journal").Range("J1").Validation.Formula1
    strRange2 = Replace(strRange, "=", "")  'Get rid of the equals sign
    Set inputRange = Evaluate(strRange2)
    For Each c In inputRange
        Workbooks("sample.xlsm").Worksheets("Credit Research Journal").Range("J1").Value = c.Value
        Workbooks("sample.xlsm").Sheets("Credit Research Journal").Activate
        Workbooks("sample.xlsm").RefreshAll
        FinalRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        Cells(8, 1).Resize(FinalRow - 7, 10).Copy
        Workbooks("Book2.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet3").Activate
        NextRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        Set Current = Cells(NextRow, 1)
        Current.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Next c

End Sub
```

I used two string variables `strRange` and `strRange2` so that you can easily step through with the debugger and see what is happening.

Also I am assuming that your dropdown list is being populated by values that are references to other cells.

Comment: it worked perfectly. Thank you so much. would you mind explaining to me what does .Validation.Formula1 do? is that a buildin function or a variable? if a variable, what does it refer to? if a function, what does it call?

Comment: actually, after a closer look at the result, the code doesn't really go through the list and pick up corresponding rows. Instead, it find a value in the list, and copy same rows for multiple times. could you please advice?

Comment: What is the range that you are trying to copy?